# C application not working properly

Tags: c, directory

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char directorio[99] = "E:\\Users\\Javier\\Documents\\Universidad", fichero[99] = "solucion_enero_12.pdf";
    char letras[99]="c*o.*";
    char copiar1[99]="E:\\Users\\Javier\\Documents\\Universidad\\Numero1";
    char copiar2[99]="E:\\Users\\Javier\\Documents\\Universidad\\Numero2";



    copiar(copiar1,copiar2);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void copiar(char *dir_orig,char *dir_dest){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA datos;
    HANDLE hFind;
    char destino[99];
    SetCurrentDirectory(dir_orig);
    hFind=FindFirstFile("*.*",&datos);
    if(hFind==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("No encontrado\n ");
        exit(1);
            }
    if(!(datos.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)){
        sprintf(destino,"%s%s",&dir_dest, datos.cFileName);
        printf("%s\n",datos.cFileName);
        CopyFile(datos.cFileName,destino,FALSE);
    }

    while(FindNextFile(hFind,&datos))
    {
        if(!(datos.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)){
            sprintf(destino,"%s%s",&dir_dest,datos.cFileName);
            printf("%s\n",datos.cFileName);
            CopyFile(datos.cFileName,destino,FALSE);
        }
    }
```

}

The function copiar(   ,   ) should copy everything inside the folder of the first path into the second folder. but it is just copying the files inside itself and renaming them in a weird way. Debugger isn't even working. Any help?

Comment: Get the debugger to work.

Comment: Your `sprintf` usage looks suspect.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i cant, it works on other projects but not on this one.

Comment: @Galen how should I use it?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and @KevinDTimm's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with:

`sprintf(destino,"%s%s",&dir_dest, datos.cFileName);`

should not have `&` before dir_dest, **and should have a path separator between directory and filename**

and, the line immediately following :

`printf("%s\n",datos.cFileName);`

should also have `destino` included (note that doing that would probably have already answered your question / and solved your problem

Comment: I believe he might also be missing the path separator between the directory and file name.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying this for like 3 hours, it was just spacing the "%s%s"  and  deleting &   ty

Comment: Happy to help (with an assist from @Galen)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because you do copying only if `datos` is not a directory:

```
if(!(datos.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
```